# slide down and slide up with different div's

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div named first , and another div named second ,both are independent div's.what i need is to be able to slide down div second when the user's mouse hovers over div first,and keep it that way if the user is hovering over div second ,otherwise slide up div second.

```
$("#first").hover(function(e)
{
    $("#second").slideDown(1000);
},function(e){
    $("#second").slideUp(1000);
});
```

This is my current code,but it slides up div second ,when i hover over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display the `div#second` even user is `hovering` over it. So you should also handle hover for `div#second` too. And additionally you should use `.stop()` to clear up the animation queue every time before a new animation starts.

Try,

```
$("#first,#second").hover(function(e)
{
    $("#second").stop().slideDown(1000);
},function(e){
    $("#second").stop().slideUp(1000);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/rDk87/)